# dual monitor: move all windows from 1st monitor to 2nd monitor

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, gnome2

Is there a way to move all windows from the 1st monitor to the 2nd monitor while the 1st monitor is turned off? This is on gnome 2.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to turn off the 1st monitor in your display settings. Try running gnome-display-properties or nvidia-settings if you are running the nvidia drivers or aticonfig if you have ATI.